# ASP.NET Core Setting Response.ContentType via IActionFilter results in 406 Not allowed

Tags: asp.net-core, content-type, action-filter, http-status-code-406, http-accept-header

I'm using IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted (ASP.NET Core 3.1) to set context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType with a media type and charset, e.g. application/json; charset=utf-8.

However when setting the ContentType property the response status code 406 Not allowed is returned.

I've tried:

- Setting the Accept headers of the request (Accept: application/json; Accept-Charset: utf-8);
- services.AddMvc(options => options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = false);
- services.AddMvc(options => options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true);

plus combinations of the above, but the 406 keeps coming back.

Then I tried to set the response content type without the charset and this worked!!

This makes sense probably as Accept=application/json != Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8, however I can't find a way to set the charset now.

Any thoughts?

Cheers,

Peter

Comment: Seems that your client can't accept the uft-8 charset , you can refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406)

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! It does actually, it is simply a HttpClient with the right Accept headers set. When the Accept is set to application/json and Content Type to application/json it works. When setting Content Type is set to application/json; charset=utf-8 it doesn't work anymore, even when Accept Charset is set to utf-8.